# Got an Error declaring vector - expected expression

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, assignment-operator, stdinitializerlist

Got an Error "expected expression" in line 15. Don't know what it needs and how to solve it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int q;
    cin >> q;
    string command, task;
    int day;
    int index = 1;
    vector<int> m_Lenght;
    m_Lenght = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31}; //<-- Here in line 15
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a compiler that supports at least C++ 11.

Comment: And do you mean m_Length instead of m_Lenght?

Comment: Change the two lines into one: `vector<int> m_Lenght{0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31};`, or change the one line to: `m_Lenght = vector<int>{0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31};`

Comment: @Eljay Your comment does not make a sense.

Comment: @Eljay None of these two options are working.

Comment: @АнтонАнаньев As I have written his comment does not make a sense. The problem is that you need to use a compiler that supports the C++ 11.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I believe I use compiler with C++ 11.

Comment: @АнтонАнаньев [This compiles with no errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b1223e0d7cd8f60).  Why not mention the compiler you're using, and the command-line you are using to compile the program.

Comment: @АнтонАнаньев The error message means that the compiler does not support the C++ 11. If it can support the C++ 11 then set the corresponding option of the compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Eclipse Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)

Comment: @АнтонАнаньев It is not a compiler:)

Comment: @АнтонАнаньев -- That is not the compiler.  Eclipse is the code editor.  The compiler will be g++, clang, etc.  It's too bad a knowledge of the tools that are used to build a C++ program are not stressed -- instead it's IDE's hiding all of this information.

Comment: Assuming the compiler is relatively up to date, you can turn on C++ 11 support in eclipse with Project->Properties and in the dialog that pops up, expand C/C++ Build and select Settings. Find the C++ compiler settings, expand its menu, and find Dialect. Set Language Standard to ISO C++11 or more recent. If the compiler is too out of date to support the standard, you should get a relatively easy to read error message when you attempt the next build.

Comment: Thank a lot guys. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers before adopting the C++ 11 did not support the initialization of containers using  `std::initializer_list`. There were no initializer list constructors.

So either use a more modern compiler or select the option of your compiler that allows to use features introduced in the C++ 11.